# Append file in python in a compute Engine ssh problem

Tags: python, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have a debian Instance in the compute engine,

I run a python script on it,
At the end of the script I have the following code to append a tkt file.

```
with open("Optimisation.txt", "a+") as myfile:

            myfile.write(str(Results))
            myfile.write("\n" )
```

I run my python script with `python MyScript.py &`

when I let the ssh console open, it correctly appends the file but when I close the console, the scipt continues working but the file is not appened anymore.

When I reopen the console and enter `sudo -s` & `ps -fux` I can see the scipt correctly running.

On my computer and my open console debian it works but not when I am closing the console.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "console"? Could you run this script in the local machine?
Also you can check your journal logs to see if any other processes are interrupting your script by following this link:
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/journalctl.1.en.html

Answer (score 1):

python MyScript.py & would run the process in background using a subshell. If the current shell is terminated (say by logout), all subshells are also terminated so the background process would also be terminated. The nohup command ignores the HUP signal and thus even if the current shell is terminated, the subshell and the myprocess.out would continue to run in the background.

Ideally, you should invoke your script with the below command

```
nohup python MyScript.py > MyOutput.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thank you I am trying can you explain this part of your explication please ? '> MyOutput.log 2>&1 &'

Comment: It will redirect STDOUT and STDERR to the log file (MyOutput.log)

Comment: @guiguidm 2 is the Unix file number for stderr. 1 is the Unix file number for stdout. The `2>&1` means write stderr to stdout instead of stderr. That way both stderr and stdout can be redirected to the same file.